# Search Result Source by ContentType causes zero results

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to build a SP 2013 Result Source that returns my specific content type.  Using the Build Tool I have this Query Text:

```
{searchTerms} ContentType:0x0120D520001F10DE640DA39D48A542F16414CE507B*
```

Which returns nothing.  I have run a full crawl and have items of that content type in my site.

I noticed that when switching to the Test tab of the Build Your Query page the search query is modified somehow into this:

```
ContentType:0x0120D520001F10DE640DA39D48A542F16414CE507B* -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

I am not liking the addition of the -ContentClass as it appears may be messing things up a bit.

What must else I do to get this to return?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I changed it to this and now it works.  I have no idea why the builder uses the GUID and why it wont work.

```
{searchTerms} ContentType:"Engineering Project"
```